# Window positioning in C#?

Tags: c#

When I run my application I want to display my window at right side bottom above the task bar. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

[Form.DesktopLocation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.desktoplocation%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> Desktop coordinates are based on the
>   working area of the screen, which
>   excludes the taskbar. The coordinate
>   system of the desktop is pixel based.
>   If your application is running on a
>   multimonitor system, the coordinates
>   of the form are the coordinates for
>   the combined desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article that describes how to do it.

http://dotnetperls.com/position-windows

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the size of the screen as a Rectangle object from the `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` property.

You can use this information to set the Left and Top properties of your form to the difference between the widths and heights of the Screen rectangle and your form, as such:

`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
   this.Left = screen.Width - this.Width;
   this.Top = screen.Height - this.Height;
}`

Comment: i mean if i want my window exactly middle of the monitor then

Comment: If you want the window in the middle of your screen, that's actually a lot easier, simply set your forms StartPosition property to CenterScreen. I don't think this works if your application is already running, but if it is, you can tweak my answer to set the left and top to be 1/2 of the screen height/width minute 1/2 of your forms height/width. Play around with the code a bit to get a feel for what it does, then you'll be able to modify it to suit your needs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
```